# Cannot select wifi network from drop down menu?

Tags: wifi

I've been messing around with my /etc/network/interfaces file so that I can try to get a static IP with wifi. Since I rebooted, it says I am connected to my AP, but I cannot select any other wifi networks (see the X appearing where the wifi symbol should be. When I click it, nothing happens).

[image]

When I run: `service dhcpcd status` I get the following message: `[FAIL] dhcpcd is not running ... failed!`

How can I re-enable the menu that lets me select different wifi networks?

Comment: Have a look at `grep dhcpcd /var/log/syslog | tail -n 25`.

Comment: If "messing around with my /etc/network/interfaces file" has broken it put it back the way it was. If you want help paste the content of the file in your question.